# Can't install ffi gem, Rails fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, ffi

While creating creating an integration test via `rails generate integration_test foo` it declined with

```
Could not find ffi-1.0.9 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I ran `bundle install` to install missing gems, but with no success. Still the same error. I have `gem 'ffi'` in my Gemfile.

I switched the gemfile line to `gem 'ffi', :git => 'git://github.com/ffi/ffi.git'` and `bundle install`ed again. It did all sort of stuff and wrote "Your bundle is complete" at the end.

However when I run the `rails generate...` command again I get:

`git://github.com/ffi/ffi.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run 'bundle install'`

What the hell is going on with this ffi?

Comment: Fetching: ffi-1.0.9.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed ffi-1.0.9
1 gem installed

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem and solved it by removing the `Gemfile.lock` and re-run `bundle install`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try 'bundle exec rails generate...'

Answer (score 0):

bundle install was failing because it could ffi failed with NoMethodError for spec.

Removing Gemfile.lock, empty the gemset and doing bundle install worked.